# Create a pdf file, write in it and return its byte stream with PyMuPDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymupdf

Using PyMuPDF, I need to create a PDF file, write some text into it, and return its byte stream.

This is the code I have, but it uses the filesystem to create and save the file:

```py
    import fitz
    path = "PyMuPDF_test.pdf"
    doc = fitz.open()
    page = doc.newPage()
    where = fitz.Point(50, 100)
    page.insertText(where, "PDF created with PyMuPDF", fontsize=50)
    doc.save(path)  # Here Im saving to the filesystem
    with open(path, "rb") as file:
        return io.BytesIO(file.read()).getvalue()
```

Is there a way I can create a PDF file, write some text in it, and return its byte stream without using the filesystem?

Comment: I think this problem already was on Stackoverflow - if `save()` accepts `file-like` object or `file-handler` then you can use `io.BytesIO` in `save()`

Comment: BTW: using filesystem you can write it much simpler `return open(path, "rb").read()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking [save()](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#Document.save) I found [write()](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#Document.write) which gives it directly as bytes

```
import fitz

#path = "PyMuPDF_test.pdf"

doc = fitz.open()
page = doc.newPage()
where = fitz.Point(50, 100)
page.insertText(where, "PDF created with PyMuPDF", fontsize=50)

print(doc.write())
```